# VB.NET Error in Editing data?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Currently when i try to edit a customers information it edits every customers information to the same thing.

I don't receive any errors it just for example if i change a customers First name to John it changes every customer to John

I use the save button to both add and edit customers
So here is my code for all of that any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
    Private Sub btnSave_Customerform_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave_Customerform.Click
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        If CurrentCustomerID = -1 Then
            ' ' ADDING NEW CUSTOMER 
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Insert into Tbl_Customer ([First name] , [Secondname] , [Address] , [Postcode], [DOB], [Phone number]) " &
                    "Values ([@First name], [@Second name], [@Address], [@Postcode], [@DOB], [@Phone number])"

                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@First name", txtFirstname.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Second name", txtLastname_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txtAddress_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Postcode", txtPostcode_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", datDOB_Customerform.Value.Date)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone number", txtPhonenumber_Customerform.Text)


                'Validations
                If txtFirstname_Customerform.Text.Length > 30 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("ERROR")
                End If
                .ExecuteNonQuery()

                ' Generates Customer ID
                .CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                CurrentCustomerID = .ExecuteScalar
                Txt_CustID.Text = CurrentCustomerID
            End With

        Else
            'EDIT CUSTOMER
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Update Tbl_Customer " &
                    "Set Secondname = @Secondname, " &
                    "First name= @First name, " &
                    "DOB = @DOB, " &
                    "PostCode = @PostCode " &
                    "Where [CurrentCustomerID] = @CurrentCustomerID"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Secondname", txtLastname_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@First name", txtFirstname.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", datDOB_Customerform.Value.Date)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", txtPostcode_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone number", txtPhonenumber_Customerform.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentCustomerID", CurrentCustomerID)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()







            End With
            cn.Close()

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I repurposed this code from another project here is the code for that which seems to work fine

```
    Private Sub butSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles butSave.Click
    If DbConnect() Then
        Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand
        If CurrentStudentID = -1 Then
            '--------------------
            'Adding a New Student
            '--------------------
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Insert into Students (Surname, FirstNames, DateOfBirth, Postcode) " & "Values (@Surname, @FirstNames, @DateOfBirth, @PostCode)"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TxtSurname.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstNames", TxtFirstName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DatDOB.Value.Date)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", TxtPostcode.Text)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
                'Now get the auto generated ID of this new student
                .CommandText = "Select @@Identity"
                CurrentStudentID = SQLCmd.ExecuteScalar
                lblStudentID.Text = CurrentStudentID
            End With
        Else
            '--------------------
            'Editing an exisiting Student
            '--------------------
            With SQLCmd
                .Connection = cn
                .CommandText = "Update Students " &
                    "Set Surname = @Surname, " &
                    "FirstNames = @FirstNames, " &
                    "DateOfBirth = @DateOfBirth, " &
                    "PostCode = @PostCode " &
                    "Where StudentID = @CurrentStudentID"
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", TxtSurname.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstNames", TxtFirstName.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", DatDOB.Value.Date)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostCode", TxtPostcode.Text)
                .Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentStudentID", CurrentStudentID)
                .ExecuteNonQuery()
            End With
        End If
        cn.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What DB is this? `"First name = @First name` - the names are not [escaped] so this should not work at all ...

Comment: It works for when i add a customer that works just fine it just changes everything instead of one thing. Its an access database btw

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Is it ever stepping into the `Else` part where you're updating? Have you checked the contents of the DB, especially what the `CurrentCustomerID` of each record is?

Comment: Ive set the current customer ID = to the customer id of the searched customer. Basically you search for a customer and then their details appear the user shoudl then be able to change information and save it which updates the database

Comment: 1) Do not use spaces in the parameter names. 2) Do not surround the parameter references in the SQL with `[` and `]`. 3) [Can we stop using AddWithValue already](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) explains why AddWithValue can give unexpected results.

Comment: How do you suggest i change it im unsure of what you mean?

Comment: 1) Instead of "@First name" use "@FirstName" and so on for all the parameter names. Remember to change them in the SQL statement too.

Comment: 2) `Values ([@First name], [@Second name], [@Address], [@Postcode], [@DOB], [@Phone number])` should then become `Values (@FirstName, @SecondName, @Address, @Postcode, @DOB, @PhoneNumber)`.

Comment: Im copying some code i did for another project and for that it worked fine. Ill add it to my code at the top

Comment: "for that it worked fine " yes but in that sample from your other project you don't have any parameter names with spaces in them, which was Andrew's whole point

Comment: 3) Adding parameters should look like `.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter With {.ParameterName = "@FirstName", .OleDbType = OleDbType.VarWChar, .Size = 30, .Value = txtFirstname.Text})` where you change the .OleDbType and .Size to match the column type in the database.

Comment: Oh, and 4) It would be prudent to rename the database columns to remove the spaces. Otherwise they will keep on making programming with them a nuisance ;)

Comment: Ive removed all the spaces and the parameters from both the code and the database and i still have the same problem

Comment: @haz14 That is good progress :) Now, if you change the AddWithValue parts to the form I showed a few minutes ago, we can be sure that that is not what is messing up the SQL query. Umm... I just had a thought: does each database record have a different CurrentCustomerID? It could be that they are accidentally all the same.

Comment: Im not quite sure what you mean in your changes could you perhaps show me? Sorry im quite new to this

Comment: @haz14 If you look at my comment that starts "3) Adding parameters should look like..." you'll see what I mean. If the CurrentCustomerID is a number then it doesn't need the .Size value.